# How Admin Can Unset All The Cookies Of The Users

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

I have a website that makes art contest every day and at 9 pm the admin decides someone as the winner he also wants to unset all the cookies of all the users.

My Cookie that I am setting for one day

```
$cookie_name = "participated";
$cookie_value = "yes";
    
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
```

Is there any way that It can be unset every day at 9 pm or is there any way that the admin can unset all the cookies every day at 9 pm?

Edited : Code tried

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

if(date("H") <= 12){
    $date = date("H");
}else{
    
$date = date("H")-12;
}

echo 9-$date;
?>
```

Comment: You will have to calculate the cookies expiration time when you set the cookie so that it will automatically expire at 21:00.  You cannot just reach out into the internet and remove cookies from your USers PC's from your server

Comment: So how can I make a logic for the expiry date

Comment: Can you please answer my question For My better understanding

Comment: The logic of the code

Comment: Dont you want to have a try, see if you can at least get close to it

Comment: Yes I should try it ok then

Comment: If user does not reload the page, that will never happen.

Comment: @MarkusZeller True, if they dont reload the page then there is no issue, when they do (after 9PM today) it will automatically expire then

Comment: I tried to do but my code goes like this but not working

Comment: Ya its is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the DateTime builtin class you can simply do

```
$cookie_name = "participated";
$cookie_value = "yes";

// get the timestamp of today @ 9PM to use as the expiry time
$expire = (new DateTime('today 21:00:00'))->getTimestamp();

// or with a specific timezone
//$expire = (new DateTime('today 21:00:00', new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata')))->getTimestamp();

setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, $expire, "/");
```

Comment: But you should also check that current time is less than 21:00. Like this `if (date('H')<21)`. Otherwise you should use `new DateTime('tomorrow 21:00:00')`

Comment: Please can you post the correct answer with Full details

Comment: Thanks RiggsFolly For your answer ✌️